# How to insert html/base64 image into new pdf in non-binary mode via php?

Tags: php, pdf, png, fpdf

Right now i'm using fPDF and PHP 7.4 this way:

```php
<?php
$imgData = 'iVBORw0KGg...lFTkSuQmCC'; // This is 100% png image
$imgPath = '/tmp/example.png';
$imgFile = \imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($imgData));
\imagepng($imgFile, $imgPath);
$pdf = new \FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image($imgPath, 15, 10, 180, 320, 'png');
$pdf->Output('F', '/tmp/bin.pdf');
\unlink($imgPath);
```

Or even this:

```php
<?php
$imgData = 'iVBORw0KGg...lFTkSuQmCC'; // This is 100% png image
$imgFile = 'data://text/plain;base64,' . $imgData;
$pdf = new \FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image($imgFile, 15, 10, 180, 320, 'png');
$pdf->Output('F', '/tmp/bin.pdf');
```

It works well, but creating this way gives me fully binary pdf-file.

But i need "text representation" of pdf. I mean something like that `cat /tmp/txt.pdf`:

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj
... some other data ...
<<
/Info 17 0 R
/Size 23
/Root 1 0 R
>>
startxref
6878
%%EOF
```

How can achieve this?

General idea is that i need to send this PDF as a string inline via JSON-encoded request and receiver requires this type of representation.

Comment: Why not encoding the whole pdf in base64 ? Like that you have an ascii representation and will be able to send it thought json

Comment: Pdf is a binary format. Even though you can restrict the bytes in a pdf to be only ASCII codes, treating such a pdf as a string can damage the internal cross references of the file. But base 64 encoding it for transport is indeed an option.

Comment: @FabienSa it’s about legacy. I need one more version to go to base64 (as I see from answers is better option).

Comment: @mkl my pdf is very simple always. How can I restrict to only ascii? And have time to make a BC to base64 representation.

Comment: Like I first saw pdf in fedex api. And they are sending pdf files this (strictly ascii) way. Never thought it can be problematic.

Comment: FPDF always embeds images in a binary form.

Comment: *"my pdf is very simple always. How can I restrict to only ascii?"* - use the *hexadecimal form* for all strings, use *ASCII hex encoding* or *ASCII base-85 encoding* for all streams, and use the *hexadecimal notation* for bytes outside the ASCII range in all names. I don't know how you make FPDF do so; @Olivier's comment seems to indicate that you can't. *"Like I first saw pdf in fedex api. And they are sending pdf files this (strictly ascii) way. Never thought it can be problematic."* - it is not difficult per se, merely hardly any PDF library offers this because it's not needed.

Comment: Got it. Thank you all for making situation more clear for me, it was not that clear at first sight.